# Why does the ending text for Portal 1 look wrong lately?

Tags: portal

The ending sequence looks broken on both Windows and Linux, more so on Linux. Here's what I mean:

Windows:

> [image]

Linux, the text is positioned even worse, and notice how the font is wrong too:

> [image]

For comparison, here's one I found online that looks correct. Notice the font has proper margins, and the ascii art isn't cropped off the side.

> [image]

Any idea why this is? Does anyone else see this on their end, or is it just my own PC being weird?

Comment: The Windows and online images are using a serif font while the Linux image has a sans-serif font. My guess is that it could be corrupted fonts.